# Peculiar tikz-external, pgfplots, tikzscale combination problem

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-external, tikzscale

I want to use `\tikzexternalize` and `tikzscale` with `pgfplots`' `\addplot graphics` command and `\clip=false` option.
I am using three files: `A.png`, `A.tikz` and `A.tex`.
`A.png` can be any graphics file.
`A.tikz` contains the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=0.5\textwidth,
xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=5,
clip=false,
]
\addplot graphics [xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=5] {A.png};
%\addplot coordinates {(1,1)(2,3)(3,2)};
\node[anchor=south east] at (rel axis cs:-0.05,1) {(a)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The content of `A.tex` is:

```
\documentclass[crop,10pt,border=0]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{tikzscale}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\tikzsetnextfilename{Figure-A}
\setlength{\textwidth}{510pt}
This is some text.
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{A.tikz}
% \input{A.tikz}
\end{document}
```

Compiling the document like this, I get an error and the external file is not created. I found out, that the problem arises from the combination of of the following lines:
`\tikzexternalize`
`\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{A.tikz}`
`clip=false`
`\addplot graphics [xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=5] {A.png};`
If I omit any one of these commands, there will be no error but obviously I cannot use the coresponding option either:
- If I omit `\tikzexternalize`, there is no error but also no external file and the tikz code is compiled in every run.
- If I omit `clip=false`, there is no error, an external file is created but I cannot draw anything outside but relative to the axis.
- If I omit `\addplot graphics [xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=5] {A.png};` e.g. by using the `\addplot coordinates` instead, I get no error, an external file is created but I cannot use external graphics
- If I omit `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{A.tikz}` and use `\input{A.tikz}` instead, it works but the result is not scaled properly.
So my question is: Is there any way to make these four commands/options work together?

Comment: A.Tikz is not a graphics file. It expects an image not code. Also pgfplots has width and height options so you don't need tikzscale

Comment: @percusse When you use `tikzscale`, it indeed does support code. And as stated in the question, it does work with the `.tikz` if any of the other three options is omitted. I do know there is width and height in pgfplots, but it is very time consuming to find the right parameters to fit the result to a certain scale, especially when using `groupplots`. `tikzscale` is very powerful in achieving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get into the `axis` environment by using `every axis/.append style` and then you can comment out the `clip=false` option. I enclose an example and a preview of the result, please try it if it is working for you with all those group plots.

```
%! *latex mal-A.tex
%   with shell escape on
\documentclass[crop,10pt,border=0]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\def\malkeyfile{mal-A.tikz}
\begin{filecontents*}{\malkeyfile}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=0.5\textwidth,
  xmin=0, xmax=5, ymin=0, ymax=5, 
  %clip=false, % Now, there is no need for this option anymore.
  every axis/.append style={after end axis/.code={\node[anchor=south east] at (rel axis cs:-0.05,1) {(a)};}},
  ]
\addplot graphics [xmin=2.5, xmax=5, ymin=0, ymax=5] {example-image.png}; % This picture is a part of the mwe package.
\addplot coordinates { (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4.5,4) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}
\tikzsetnextfilename{Figure-mal-A}
\setlength{\textwidth}{510pt}
This is some text.
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{\malkeyfile}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe with a single picture]

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware, that one had access to the `axis cs` from outside the `axis` environment. Now, without the `clip=false` option, the rest works just fine. Still interesting, that only the combination of the four options will produce the error...